# snackbar.dismis is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

Actually i am trying to invoke the Snackbar from the Fragment class, and the problem is on first time the snackbar is shown succesfully but on Second time the snackbar.dismis is not working
Code :

```
Snackbar snackbar; View sbView; TextView textView;
private void showSnackBar(Boolean bool) {

    snackbar = Snackbar
            .make(getView(), getResources().getString(R.string.set_pickup_time), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    sbView = snackbar.getView();
    textView = sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    if (bool)
        snackbar.show();
    else {
            if (snackbar.isShown())
        snackbar.dismiss();
    }
}
```

And sometime i got `NPE` when i check the `if (snackbar.isShown())`

Comment: Where is `show();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you are creating a new snackbar and then checking if it's shown without showing it. You have to move around your code something like this:

```
    if (bool){

        snackbar = Snackbar.make(getView(), getResources().getString(R.string.set_pickup_time), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        sbView = snackbar.getView();
        textView = sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        snackbar.show();

    }else if (snackbar!=null && snackbar.isShown())

           snackbar.dismiss();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to create a snackbar once.

```
Snackbar snackbar; View sbView; TextView textView;
private void showSnackBar(Boolean bool) {

if(snackbar == null) {
  snackbar = Snackbar
        .make(getView(),  getResources().getString(R.string.set_pickup_time), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
  sbView = snackbar.getView();
  textView = sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
  textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}

if (bool)
    snackbar.show();
else {
        if (snackbar.isShown())
    snackbar.dismiss();
}
}
```